# Firefox: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

I'm hosting a custom page on a RaspberryPi3 as a home dashboard. It renders fine in Chrome and on mobile browsers, but doesn't work in Firefox on the desktop.

Below is the error I receive in the console:

```
Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
```

However, I"m loading jQuery before Bootstrap.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
...
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
...
  <script src="dist/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head><!--end head-->
...
```

When type `$.fn.jquery` into the console, I get this back.

```
TypeError: $.fn is undefined
```

I'm assuming jQuery isn't being loaded properly? Again, Chrome works without issues and renders properly. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is there any console error on your pageload, stating that your jquery file could not be loaded?

Comment: No, it all looks ok.  ```GET 
https://10.10.2.32/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css [0ms]
GET 
https://10.10.2.32/dist/jquery-2.2.4.min.js [0ms]
GET 
https://10.10.2.32/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js [1ms]
GET 
https://10.10.2.32/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 437ms]
Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery```

Comment: are you sure jquery is loading? try to comment the js bootstrap an write a quick alert message with jquery

Comment: What happens when you press $ at console?

Comment: @AlessanderFrança, I receive the following options: $x, $_, $0, $$, $.

Comment: Why bootstrap script is being called twice?

Comment: @jcvegan, one is CSS, one is JS.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is the jQuery version

See the bower.json from bootstrap:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.6/bower.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "jquery": "1.9.1 - 2"
  }
```

Try the basic template from bootstrap site:

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template

Comment: I tried using a correct version of jQuery and it still does the same thing.

Comment: Did you try copy and paste the basic template?

Comment: I tried using the template (with jQuery and Bootstrap on a CDN) and it worked. However, it's still not working when I load it locally. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, since the files **do** load in the Developer Tools.

Comment: Did you try to use npm install?

Comment: I'm using the files from the website, but I'll try that.